# Usage StringBuffer and String?

Tags: java, string

As known `String` is immutable in Java. I have the following method's body which return `String`:

```
Partner partner = context.getComponent(ComponentNames.PARTNER_COMPONENT_NAME);
String lastAccesDate = partner.getLastAccessDate();
if(lastAccesDate == null) {
    return "";
}
lastAccesDate = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_PATTERN).format(); //1
return lastAccesDate;
```

The thing is because of string immutability, a new String object will be created at `//1`, so actually I'll have two String Objects, the first one contains `partner.getLastAccessDate();`, the second one `new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_PATTERN).format();`. The overhead is not good, how can I avoid it?

Comment: Use StringBuilder instead of String

Comment: @Sharpedge Why don't a StringBuffer? One's mutable, so we can modify the string it contains.

Comment: from java docs **"Every string buffer has a capacity. As long as the length of the character sequence contained in the string buffer does not exceed the capacity, it is not necessary to allocate a new internal buffer array. If the internal buffer overflows, it is automatically made larger. As of release JDK 5, this class has been supplemented with an equivalent class designed for use by a single thread, StringBuilder. The StringBuilder class should generally be used in preference to this one, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization."**

Comment: What does `lastAccesDate = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_PATTERN).format();` do? The `format` method must have a `Date` as an argument. Also, although it is true that a new `String` is created when using the format (I looked at the Java source code) this is not because of String immutability, but **despite** immutability. It is theoretically possible that the `format` method would call `String.intern(String)` in order to save memory since the `String` cannot be changed anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use `StringBuffer` in case of multithreading(i.e. if you need a thread-safe, mutable sequence of character) otherwise use  `StringBuilder`

Comment: This method is from the web application, so I do use StringBuffer, don't I?

Comment: @St.Antario it depends if you are creating the Object inside the method something like `public void foo() {StringBuilder sb=//....}` then `StringBuilder` is the choice to go because the object will be created on stack and every thread will have it own so no problem. But if you need to declare the object outside the method i.e. on the heap then StringBuffer is must

Answer (score 0):

see when you assign second time string to the String object lastAccessDate, there is no overhead as automaticaly garbage collector will free the space which occupied by first object because no object has reference to the same. so no need to worry about overhead